# Connection error when sending web requests on unity WebGL build only

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, asp.net-web-api, unity-webgl, unitywebrequest

I'm trying to send a post request to my login API (located on same system) that I made on ASP.NET in c# with my unity WebGL build as client, but for some reason it always pops out a connection error on client-side immediately while nothing is popping up on the console for my API.
[image]
Here is my code for the post request:

```
using(UnityWebRequest apiRequest = UnityWebRequest.Post(uri, jsonRequest, "application/json")){
    apiRequest.SetRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    apiRequest.SetRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*");
    apiRequest.SetRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
    yield return apiRequest.SendWebRequest();

    //apiRequest returns a token on successful authentication
    if (apiRequest.result > UnityWebRequest.Result.Success){
        Debug.Log("API Request: " + apiRequest.result);
        loginPending = false;
        yield break;
    }
    else if (apiRequest.downloadHandler.text.ToLower() == "invalid credentials"){
        Debug.Log("Login failed");
        loginPending = false;
        yield break; 
    }
    else token = apiRequest.downloadHandler.text;
}
```

I want to also add that this worked on the editor and on the desktop build.

One thing I've tried was enabling CORS on both the WebGL client and API, I'm not too sure if I properly setup the one on the API but this is the one I have and it still did not work and I got the same error:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var settings = new Settings();

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: "WebGLOrigins",
        policy =>
        {
            policy.AllowAnyOrigin();
            policy.AllowAnyMethod();
            policy.AllowAnyHeader();
        });
});

builder.Configuration.Bind("Settings", settings);
builder.Services.AddSingleton(settings);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseCors("WebGLOrigins");

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

My controller containing the post request:

```
[EnableCors("WebGLOrigins")]
[HttpPost("login")]
public string Post([Required] LoginCreds loginCreds){
    loginCreds.playerName = loginCreds.playerName.ToLower();

    //MAKE SURE TO SET USER OFFLINE WHEN LOGGED OUT OR DISCONNECTED
    SqlConnection sqlConn = _playerService.SqlOpen();
    if (_playerService.IsUserOnline(sqlConn, loginCreds.playerName)) return "User already Online";

    //sanitize user input before authenticating login creds
    (bool, string) authenticateResult = _playerService.LdapAuthenticate(loginCreds.playerName, loginCreds.playerPass);
    if(authenticateResult.Item1) _playerService.SendTokenToDB(loginCreds.playerName, authenticateResult.Item2);

    Console.WriteLine("LDAP API service finished");
    return authenticateResult.Item2;
}
```

Comment: What is the URI you are passing? Is the WebGL hosted on/by the same Asp.NET solution? In that case you could skip the base URL (host name) as it already sits within that domain

Comment: They're on different solutions but located in the same system for now so Im using localhost uri. In any case I've solved the issue now, I checked many documentations on how to enable cors but I only saw one that put the attribute on top of the controller class itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the way to solve this was to also add the [EnableCors("WebGLOrigins")] attribute on top of the controller class that held the post method I've been trying to use. I only saw that you can do that on this article

https://dzone.com/articles/cors-in-net-core-net-core-security-part-vi